# Metro app - Translating UI resources - import content from external xml

Tags: xml, localization, import, microsoft-metro, translation

I've started translating a windows 8 metro app following this doc http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965329.aspx. My question is: is there a way to import content in the .resw file, from an external .xml (used for the android version of the same app)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is, if you have a translation tool.

First, you need to convert your .resw file into something most translation tools can use. There is the [Multilingual App Toolkit for Visual Studio 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/hh848309.aspx) that can convert it to .xlf (XLIFF) file.

We use SDL Trados internally, but there are other tools that can handle XML. You can import your Android XML and put it into a TM (Translation Memory) and then use the TM to automatically translate your Win8 resw file. 
There is no automatic conversion from Android to .rews, what Trados does, is match the already translated strings.
E.g. in Android: DE = "Daten speichern" -> EN = "Save data"
You likely have the DE version in your Android an in your .resw file. So Trados will automatically translate the same strings in your .resw file too.

There is a free trial edition of SLD Trados available.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your answer: is SLD Trados useful to import automatically my xml into the .resw, or exprot the xml in a .rews format?

Comment: I've updated my answer a bit. But you can import your Android into Trados and then "export" it.